Joi Validation Schema Conditional Logic Not Working as Expected Based on Dynamic Value
I am having trouble with a Joi validation schema where the validation logic needs to handle different version ranges dynamically. The version ranges for legacy and current reports are defined in a configuration object, and I need the validation to adapt based on these ranges.
The validation schema does not seem to work correctly even though isLegacyReport and isCurrentReport functions return appropriate boolean values. I suspect there might be an issue with how these functions are integrated into the Joi when conditions.
export const reportValidator = {
    params: Joi.object({
        version: Joi.string()
            .required()
            .pattern(/^v[1-9]\d*$/)
    }),
    body: Joi.object({
        end_date: Joi.date().required(),
        start_date: Joi.date().required(),
        org_id: Joi.number().when(Joi.ref('/params.version'), {
            is: Joi.string().custom((value) => isCurrentReport(value)),
            then: Joi.required(),
            otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
        }),
        state_id: Joi.number().when(Joi.ref('/params.version'), {
            is: Joi.string().custom((value) => isCurrentReport(value)),
            then: Joi.required(),
            otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
        }),
        zone_id: Joi.array().items(Joi.number().required()).when(Joi.ref('/params.version'), {
            is: Joi.string().custom((value) => isCurrentReport(value)),
            then: Joi.required(),
            otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
        }),
        office_id: Joi.array()
            .items(Joi.number().required())
            .when(Joi.ref('/params.version'), {
                is: Joi.string().custom((value) => isLegacyReport(value)),
                then: Joi.required(),
                otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
            })
    })
};

